# Doctrine inheritance many chidren

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, multiple-inheritance

For a project I need to have a relation between an entity "User" <-> "Form" <-> list of "FormField". The FormField class is mother of "TextFormField", "SelectFormField"...

I used class Table Inheritance but when I do $user->getForm() there are one left join by form field child. How can I avoid that to improve performances? Single table inheritance is not possible.

Does anyone have any idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Sulu Form Bundle. Even though is not stable yet, it is really well developed. You should take a look on how they model their classes [here](https://github.com/sulu/SuluFormBundle/tree/master/Entity), and their doctrine mappings [here](https://github.com/sulu/SuluFormBundle/tree/master/Resources/config/doctrine). That should give you an idea.